# How to resume interrupted download automatically in curl?

Tags: linux, curl, resume-download

I'm working with `curl` in Linux. I'm downloading a part of a file in ftp server (using the `-r` option), but my connection is not good, it always interrupts. I want to write a script which resume download when I'm connected again.

I've used this command, but it's not working:

```
until curl -r 666-9999 -C - --retry 999 -o "path/to/file" "ftp:/path/to/remote/file"; do :; done
```

Comment: `--retry` is "supposed" to work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42873285/curl-retry-mechanism

Answer (score 134):

```
curl -L -O your_url
```

This will download the file.

Now let's say your connection is interrupted;

```
curl -L -O -C - your_url
```

This will continue downloading from the last byte downloaded

From the [manpage](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-C):

> Use "-C -" to tell curl to automatically find out where/how to resume the transfer. It then uses the given output/input files to figure that out.

Comment: yes, and if you want to specify an outfile with --output, this will work, too. with redirection (`> myfile`), it does not (obviously)

Comment: Startlingly, you can just use `curl -L -O -C - your_url` from the start, though it only runs once...

Comment: You can actually do `curl -LOC - url`  (more or less equivalent to `wget -c url`?)

Answer (score 31):

wget has been built specifically for this use case. From the man page:

```
Wget has been designed for robustness over slow or unstable network connections;
if a download fails due to a network problem, it will keep retrying until the
whole file has been retrieved.  If the server supports regetting, it will
instruct the server to continue the download from where it left off.
```

wget is available for almost all Linux distributions - it probably is already installed on yours. Just use wget to download the file, it will re-establish the network connection until the file is completely transferred.

Comment: Does wget support partial download of a file (like the -r option in curl) ?

Comment: according to the manpage it doesn't support downloading only part of the file, but the `-c` flag allows continuing a download.

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't, it does only support resuming a partially-downloaded file as Wayne said. Why would you need this? wget will take care of downloading the whole file (and only the parts you haven't already downloaded).

Comment: I want to detect automatically internet disconnection when downloading.. how can i do that ?

Comment: Well you could parse the wget output or have a separate script that pings the server...

Comment: The question asks about `curl`, not `wget`.

Comment: wget doesn't do smb:// though.  Hoping for answer on curl.

Comment: @Geremia If a suggestion resolves the underlying problem -- robustly downloading a file -- why not to share it?

Comment: I've found if the request needs to specify the byte range then wget doesn't know how to continue and will retry from the start

Comment: Don’t forget to give wget the `-c` flag, otherwise you’ll overwrite the file with a new from-scratch attempt.

Answer (score 25):

You can check the exit code in a while loop and resume until the exit code indicates that the download has succeeded:

```
export ec=18; while [ $ec -eq 18 ]; do /usr/bin/curl -O -C - "http://www.example.com/a-big-archive.zip"; export ec=$?; done
```

The example is taken from http://ilovesymposia.com/2013/04/11/automatically-resume-interrupted-downloads-in-osx-with-curl/

Comment: in my case `curl` exits with other codes, so I check for success code instead:
`export ec=18; while [ $ec -ni 0 ]; do /usr/bin/curl -O -C - "http://www.example.com/a-big-archive.zip"; export ec=$?; done`

Comment: this solution can be further simplified using `until` unstead. See [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35412943).

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you can't use `curl -L -O -C -` like in my case, to download Google Drive stuff, you can use https://curlconverter.com/wget/ to convert the curl command line to `wget` and append a `-c` or `--continue` at the end.