# Bash loop until a certain command stops failing

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to write a loop in bash which executes until a certain command stops failing (returning non-zero exit code), like so:

```
while ! my_command; do
    # do something
done
```

But inside this loop I need to check which exit code `my_command` returned, so I tried this:

```
while ! my_command; do
    if [ $? -eq 5 ]; then
        echo "Error was 5"
    else
        echo "Error was not 5"
    fi
    # potentially, other code follows...
done
```

But then the special variable `?` becomes `0` inside the loop body.
The obvious solution is:

```
while true; do
    my_command
    EC=$?
    if [ $EC -eq 0 ]; then
        break
    fi
    some_code_dependent_on_exit_code $EC
done
```

How can I check the exit code of `my_command` (called in loop header) inside loop body without rewriting this example using a `while true` loop with a break condition as shown above?

Comment: Off-topic on SO. Here is [the same question on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78512/bash-scripting-loop-until-return-value-is-0).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In addition to the well-known `while` loop, POSIX provides an `until` loop  that eliminates the need to negate the exit status of `my_command`.

```
# To demonstrate
my_command () { read number; return $number; }

until my_command; do
    if [ $? -eq 5 ]; then
        echo "Error was 5"
    else
        echo "Error was not 5"
    fi
    # potentially, other code follows...
done
```

Comment: So obvious when you know there is an `until` loop! RTFM to me. Best answer I think.

Answer (score 22):

If `true` command hurt your sensibility, you could write:

```
while my_command ; ret=$? ; [ $ret -ne 0 ];do
    echo do something with $ret
  done
```

This could be simplified:

```
while my_command ; ((ret=$?)) ;do
    echo do something with $ret
  done
```

But if you don't need *ResultCode*, you could simply:

```
while my_command ; [ $? -ne 0 ];do
    echo Loop on my_command
  done
```

or

```
while my_command ; (($?)) ;do
    echo Loop on my_command
  done
```

And maybe, why not?

```
while ! my_command ;do
    echo Loop on my_command
  done
```

But from there you could better use [`until` as chepner suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35412943/1765658)

Comment: Good answer! I never knew that `while command1; command2 ; do ...` works

Comment: Looks like the winner to me so far. I like it!

Answer (score 3):

You can get the status of a negated command from the `PIPESTATUS` built-in variable:

```
while ! my_command ; do
    some_code_dependent_on_exit_code "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
done
```

chepner's solution is better in this case, but `PIPESTATUS` is sometimes useful for similar problems.

Comment: Good point. I didn't know `PIPESTATUS` also worked in this case.

Answer (score 0):

So in my case I also need to ignore some exit codes and want to provide some useful output to the user so I wrote this up:

```
retrycmd(){
  MSG=$1
  IGNORE=$2
  shift 2
  local SLEEP_T=5
  local L_CNT=5
  local C_CNT=0
  while ((C_CNT++ < ${L_CNT})) && ! $@;do
    RET=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
    #echo "RET: ${RET}"
    for I in ${IGNORE//,/ };do # bashism: replace(/) all(/) match(,) with(/) value(<space>)
      if ((${RET} == ${I}));then
        #echo "${RET} = ${I}"
        break 2
      fi
    done
    echo "${MSG} failure ${C_CNT}"
    sleep ${SLEEP_T}
  done
  if ((${C_CNT} > ${L_CNT}));then
    echo "${MSG} failed"
    poweroff
  fi
}

#retrycmd "Doing task" "IGNORE,CSV" <CMD>
retrycmd "Ping google" "0" ping www.google.com
```