# Is "exit ${?}" correct to use in bash?

Tags: bash, syntax, exit

Let's say I code something like:

```
if [ ${?} -ne 0 ]; then 
    exit ${?}
```

Would this work properly? 
Is this correct "syntax-wise"?

Comment: See [Why is testing "$?" to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36313216/4154375).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is correct, but `$?` is reset by the `[ ... ]` command in the `if` statement. By definition, if the `if` block is entered then the `[ ... ]` test must have been successful, and `$?` is guaranteed to be `0`.

You'll need to save it in a variable.

```
result=$?
if ((result != 0)); then 
    exit "$result"
fi
```

Alternately, it's more idiomatic to test the result of a command directly rather than testing `$?`. If you do so then you don't have the problem of `$?` changing.

```
if command; then
    echo success
else
    exit   # `exit` is equivalent to `exit $?`
fi
```

If you don't care about success then you can use `||`:

```
command || exit
```

Comment: Thank you! This as well as @chepner answer cleared my doubts completely.

Comment: `if ! command; then exit "$?"; fi` (or `if ! command; then exit; fi`) will exit with status 0 if `command` returns (any) non-zero status.  `$?` gets the value of the negated status.  See [Check exit code of a program called in a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411972/4154375) for an explanation of the problem, and some solutions.

Answer (score 5):

The `[` command in your `if` statement will set `$?` after it checks. You'll need to save the original exit status before testing.

```
some_command
es=$?
if [ "$es" -ne 0 ]; then
    exit "$es"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exit on error and preserve the EXIT code of the command, you can enable the `errexit` option:

- Either with: `set -e`
- Either with: `set -o errexit`

See: `help set | grep -F -- -e`

> **-e**  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
>
> **errexit**      same as **-e**

Alternatively you can `trap` the `ERR` signal and use this to exit with the return code of the error.

This will save you from dealing with the `-e` option consequences.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

err_handler() {
  set -- $?
  printf 'The error handler caught code #%d\n' "$1" >&2
  exit "$1"
}

trap 'err_handler' ERR

create_error() {
  [ $# -ne 1 ] && return 0
  printf 'Create error #%d\n' "$1"
  return "$1"
}

create_error "$@"
```

Testing with different errors:

```sh
for e in 1 0 2; do ./a.sh "$e" ;echo $?; done
Create error #1
The error handler caught code #1
1
Create error #0
0
Create error #2
The error handler caught code #2
2
```

Comment: There are limitations and difficulties with using `set -o errexit` (`set -e`).  I'm happy to deal with them, but many people are not.  See [BashFAQ/105 (Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for good, balanced, information.

Comment: @pjh I added an alternate solution with `trap`.

Comment: You need to enable `errtrace` to make the `ERR` trap trigger on everything that would trigger with `errexit`.  See [What does `set -o errtrace` do in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25378845/4154375).  The `ERR` trap has the advantage that the handler can print helpful information about the context of the error.  (With `errexit` programs sometimes stop mysteriously for no obvious reason.)  Apart from that, the `ERR` trap has all the same limitations and difficulties as `errexit`.  Extreme caution is required.