# Problem reading command return code in bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to implement a generic function in my bash scripts that will execute a given command N times until the return code of the same is 0

The function is actually working fine, and it does retry the command and break if return is 0, but for some reason I cannot capture the return code (if non 0) to be shown.

```
$ false; echo $?
1
```

test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function execute_with_retry() {
  local retries=3;
  while ! $1; do
    echo "Command Return code was $?, we are going to retry $retries more times..."
    ((retries--)); [[ $retries -lt 0 ]] && break
  done
}

fail_cmd="false"

execute_with_retry "${fail_cmd}"

while ! $fail_cmd; do
    ret=$?
    echo "Direct Command Return code was $ret dont retry here..."
    break
done
```

```
$ ./err.sh
Command Return code was 0, we are going to retry 3 more times...
Command Return code was 0, we are going to retry 2 more times...
Command Return code was 0, we are going to retry 1 more times...
Command Return code was 0, we are going to retry 0 more times...
Direct Command Return code was 0 dont retry here...
```

As you can see above, the code I grab is always zero, here it should be 1, or whatever
Why I cannot grab the $? variable properly?

Comment: See [Bash loop until a certain command stops failing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411972/4154375).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do, much simpler:

```
execute_with_retry() {
    local retries=3 ret
    while "$@"; ret=$?; do
        ((ret == 0)) && break
        echo "Command Return code was $ret, we are going to retry $retries more times..."
        ((retries-- == 0)) && break
    done
}
```

Example:

```
$ execute_with_retry false
Command Return code was 1, we are going to retry 3 more times...
Command Return code was 1, we are going to retry 2 more times...
Command Return code was 1, we are going to retry 1 more times...
Command Return code was 1, we are going to retry 0 more times...
```

Comment: that worked perfectly, thanks a lot, i still need to understand why i wasnt capturing $? properly on my code.

One question do, why I cannot pass the command in quotes?
execute_with_retry dnf install -y mysql works fine but execute_with_retry "dnf install -y mysql" does not

Comment: @Smoke Trying to handle commands as plain strings (e.g. as arguments, variables, function outputs, etc) tends to run into parsing oddities. If you don't understand some subtleties about shell parsing, you're going to run into trouble. See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 2):

`!` inverts the return code, so `! false` exits with 0. You would have to expand it.

I would also use an array to store a command. I could see:

```
execute_with_retry() {
    local retries ret
    retries=3
    while
       ret=0
       "$@" || ret=$?
       ((ret != 0))
    do
        echo "Command Return code was $ret, we are going to retry $retries more times..."
        if ((retries-- < 0)); then
              break
        fi
    done
}
```

`function name()` is a mix of two syntaxes. Just use `name()`.

`$1` is unquoted. Check your scripts with shellcheck.

Comment: Simpler method: use `until "$@"; do ret=$? ...`.

Comment: Ahh, never figured out that ! would invert the return code, I thought it would just negate the if, that explains a lot! thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This is another, [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean, way to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash -p

function execute_with_retry
{
    local retries=3 status=0
    for ((; retries>=0; retries--)); do
        "$@" && return 0 || status=$?
        echo "Command status was $status, retrying $retries more times..."
    done
    return "$status"
}

execute_with_retry sh -c 'exit 5'

echo "Final command status was $?"
```

This version of the `execute_with_retry` function returns the status of the last retry if all retries fail.  That is more likely to be useful than a printed status if the code that called the function needs to handle the failures.