# How to wait for the IP when hiting Curl Command

Tags: shell, sh

I am hitting an API using Curl command which create an EC2 instance in AWS and return the private IP of EC2 instance.

1. newrigprivateip=$(curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d
   "'{AMI_ID:'ami-9xxxxxx'}'" $posturl)
2. echo $newrigprivateip > $build

Now sometimes my private IP takes time to generate and because of that my script failed.
Can we write the curl command in such a way that it will wait for the EC2 instance to up and  wait until the private IP return.

Comment: You can try retry mechanism for curl. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42873285/curl-retry-mechanism

Comment: Does the API not provide some identifier that lets you query the instance later to get the necessary information?

Comment: @chepner - it just provide private ip of ec2 instance apart from that nothing.

Answer (score -1):

You can try retry mechanism for curl. [Curl retry mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42873285/curl-retry-mechanism)

This might help you out.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But curl retry will create n number of EC2 instance on AWS

Comment: In that case, you need to use a loop and sleep until it retrieves the ip. You can add a timeout just incase if the VM doesn’t come up.

Comment: I don't have great knowledge about linux shell scripting. Can you give an example, how can we use loop and wait for the ip address to return ?